# what actually excludeFilters does in @ComponentScan

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have created a simple spring application to test `excludeFilters` in `@ComponentScan` annotation.

**TestConfig.java**

```
package com.example.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.FilterType;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(
        excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(
                type = FilterType.REGEX,
                pattern = {"com.example.Demo"}
        )
)
public class TestConfig {
}
```

**Demo.java**

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Demo {
}
```

*Main class* **ExcludeFilterTest.java**

```
public class ExcludeFilterTest {


  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext("com.example");
   }
}
```

when running the application I can see the Demo class is getting identified as a candidate component class and also instance is getting created.

***here are the logs***

```
12:05:34.151 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - Identified candidate component class: file [/Users/sk/learning-development/interview/logging_test/target/classes/com/example/Demo.class]
12:05:34.160 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - Identified candidate component class: file [/Users/sk/learning-development/interview/logging_test/target/classes/com/example/config/TestConfig.class]
12:05:34.172 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@687080dc
12:05:34.188 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor'
12:05:34.275 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcessor'
12:05:34.277 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerFactory'
12:05:34.278 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor'
12:05:34.282 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'demo'
12:05:34.298 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'testConfig'

Process finished with exit code 0
```

**why the Demo class instance is getting created?**

Comment: Because you are basically scanning twice. Once through how you construct the context, and another through the `@Confguration` class. If you use the configuration class to create the `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` instead of the package name it will be excluded.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead.

```java
public class ExcludeFilterTest {


  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(com.example.config.TestConfig.class);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Now it is working as expected.